# Cartthrob credit handling

Tags: cartthrob, devdemon

Am new to this expression engine  am using the cartthrob module to handle my shop item.The site base on credit system users can earn credits and use to purchase items in shop .I use devdemon credit module .can any one please tell me how to remove credits equal to the price of product from my credits table .Is there any idea of linking the credits table and cartthrob

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits has both a CartThrob and BrilliantRetail payment gateway that you can use to allow these to pay for the items with their credits. In CartThrob you will want to go to Settings > Payment Gateways and enable "Credits" from there you will enter your settings similar to this picture [image: Credits Settings in CartThrob]